# Dynamics 365 CRM connect with Phone Company Website

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I'm trying to find the address of my company Dynamics 365 CRM, and wanted to know if there's any way to get it just with admin privileges on Dynamics 365 CRM.

**Background**

My boss put me on the task of checking if it's possible to connect our crm365 to this phone company since they said their website can connect to crm365.

The problem is that we have a contract with a microsoft certified company that is in charge of crm365 (which means I don't have access to the code) and they said that such connection is impossible to do.

We have a bit of doubts about this company since the job with crm should have been done 3 months ago and right now it still has lot's of problems.

**Phone company requirements for Address:**

- Address of the destination server.
- Port of the destination server.
- Folder on the server where CRM notifications are deposited.
- Example: https://server:port/folder

  They also ask for username and password (which I assume it's from an user).

Comment: If your crm is in on-premise (server hosted) you should have/get server details from partner (contract company). If it’s crm online (url will be https://mycompany.crm.dynamics.com & it’s Microsoft cloud) then partner is right, no server access.

Comment: yes it's crm online, so i guess it won't work and we'll need to find another company?

Comment: it can still be done, it just needs a bit more work. One example would be have a SQL Server locally that gets written to. You can then have a db trigger or a scheduled job that reads from SQL and executes CRM api calls to write to CRM. Needs a bit more architectural love

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot access any server of your CRM online instance as its hosted in Microsoft Cloud. Probably you can access CRM data from any external system using Dynamics 365 CRM [Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/web-api-samples) (or [SDK Tooling Connector](https://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/25/connecting-to-microsoft-dynamics-365-using-the-sdk/))